# tail: illegal option -- -53\r error while using head and tail on same file in single script

Tags: shell, shell-script, tail, head

I am using

```
a=`head -1 Rt.in`
```

to get first value from my file and I am saving it as a variable then I am using same variable to `tail -$a` to tail last lines from my input. 
But it is giving an error:

```
tail: illegal option -- -53\r.
```

My input file has 4 columns from the third row onwards.

Here is a part of script I am using :

```
a=`head -1 Rt.in`
echo $a
tail -$a Rt.in
```

and the error in output I am getting is this:

```
tail: illegal option -- -53\r
```

And the part of input file is as follows:

```
53
FEPXUU
H    9.155963    1.289174   11.531518
H    9.004353    2.726286   11.683448
N   11.762550    3.890769   11.785241
N   10.610393    3.635048    9.544268
N   10.745642    1.175050    9.076323
N   13.210069    2.309946    9.848128
N   12.319480    0.955257   11.800435
C   12.359945    3.942548   12.929277
C   11.267322    5.027779   11.274755
H    9.052185    4.031311    6.865735
C   10.031631    3.303244    8.416945
C   10.093512    1.894663    8.164740
C    9.546565    1.312421    7.090592
. 
.
.
```

There are 53 such lines.

Can anybody will tell me why I am getting this error and how can I remove it??
If I run above script using pipes directly in terminal I am getting error as `tail: -: No such file or directory` and then list of few atoms.

Comment: Your Rt.in file was probably created on Windows. Use `dos2unix` to create a new file that Unix tools will understand.

Comment: dking, if you need to edit your question to add the '53' at the top of the input file, click the edit link at the bottom-left of it, or [this copy](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/240701/edit)

Comment: Hi i did not create this file on windows i created it on mac

Answer (score 1):

The number of lines should not be the parameter it should be:

```
tail -n $a Rt.in
```

Now you get the number of last lines that is defined in the first line of your file. This `-n` should also be used with your `head` command.

Comment: Yes i tried that too but it is giving error tail: illegal offset -- 53\r.

Comment: Can anybody edit my question there is 53 at the beginning of my input file

Comment: `tail -5` and `head -9` (using whatever digits) work and are the original options for these commands and still work.  These options are no longer documented for some reason unknown to me.

Comment: @dking the answer is in the comment on your question.  You have incorrect line endings on `Rt.in` probably because it was created on Windows.

Comment: @RobertL - this answer is correct. you should review the standard, use `-n`.